# Highlight Color in WooCommerce Drop Down?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using the WooCommerce Drop Down...

```
<?php  
the_widget( 'WC_Widget_Product_Categories', 'dropdown=1' );?><br />
```

And i'm styling it through my CSS page using: https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-css-classes/

So my question is, is it possible to change the hover/highlight color? I know the default is blue, and although that's a fine color, i would like to change it. Is that possible via: CSS? iv'e tried everything but can't seem to get this Blue color changed. any help would be great

Comment: Did you try searching anchor tag css stying?

Comment: yes, iv'e searched everywhere, and don't see a solution.

Comment: I'm gonna just assume this isn't possible after using various codes from several different websites. If anyone has a resolution, let me know. Much appreciated